# Adding headers to 307 redirection

Tags: node.js, http, redirect, http-status-code-307

Is it true that you cannot add/modified 307 header except Location? I'm trying to do that in Node.js and seems that newly added header 'X-Atlassian-Token': 'no-check' is not used by the client.

```
    res.writeHead(307,
        {
            'Location': 'http://www.mytest.com?os_authType=basic',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'X-Atlassian-Token': 'no-check'
        });
    res.end();
```

Somebody has asked the same question on Stackoverflow and one person replied -

[Is it possible to set some http headers while http-redirect(302 or 307)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235142/is-it-possible-to-set-some-http-headers-while-http-redirect302-or-307)

*"Actually, through Java objects, you can set request properties but not headers. I am looking for an answer to this myself. I believe this is a deliberate restriction to prevent faking authentication tokens and other information sent through the headers.
I will post a solution if I find one."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it true that you cannot add/modified 307 header except Location?

No, it's not true. Running your code shows a response including both the specified status code and the extra headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Location: http://www.mytest.com?os_authType=basic
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
X-Atlassian-Token: no-check
Date: Sat, 06 Jun 2015 13:40:41 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

If that's not having the effect you expect, see [this other answer to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6236892/733345):

> You should also ensure that your response headers refer to that response rather than the resource that the client is being redirected to.

That is, the `X-Atlassian-Token: no-check` header *won't* be carried across to the follow-up request (and, specifically, won't be sent by the client).

Comment: I should have worded my question better. I knew the new header was sent back to the client. What I meant is the client won't use all the attributes I added to the new header in the follow up request except location one. But thanks for confirming that the client wont.

Comment: Otherwise, you could cause a client to make a request with `X-Atlassian-Token: no-check`, which would be exactly the XSRF vulnerability that this header is intended to prevent.